# PHP OpenWeather

Tags: php, json, openweathermap

Alright so I am having some troubles understanding how to use the open weather API.
I have tried using it as

```
<?php
    $request = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=myidblablabla'); //example ID

    $jsonPHP  = json_decode($request);

    echo $jsonPHP->city;

?>
```

But I get an error saying

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in

Now there is 1 more question that I have to ask, how do I get certains City Temperature, humidity etc? From the code I received I get only Moscow

Comment: So the documentation wasn't valuable to you?

Comment: The weather has been released under an Open Source licence now? That is great news!

Comment: Was kinda, couldnt find 100% accurate answer. I tried looking into it but every attempt I had was a fail

Comment: Heres another problem I am facing now, I am trying to get the current wind and such but the problem appears 
$json['main']['wind'] as Undefined index: main

Answer (score 1):

To simplify it, you can also transform the json into array instead.

```
$jsonPHP  = json_decode($request,true);
```

Now let's discuss it briefly. According to the documentation (*http://openweathermap.org/current*),

Note also that *I've never used this API before*. I'm just trying to help here.

If you hit  [*api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139*](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139)

It responds as

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
"rain":{"3h":0},
"clouds":{"all":92},
"dt":1369824698,
"id":1851632,
"name":"Shuzenji",
"cod":200}
```

Now assuming you want to take the *weather* and *humidity* , it just :

weather :

```
echo $jsonPHP["weather"][0]["id"];
```

humidity:

```
echo $jsonPHP["main"]["humidity"];
```

Note also that, If you hit *http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139* and get the responds as

```
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```

For the case, they've explained here :

*http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401* which is :

> **Q: API calls return an error 401**
>
> A: Starting from 9 October 2015 our
>   API requires a valid APPID for access. Note that this does not mean
>   that our API is subscription-only now - please take a minute to
>   register a free account to receive a key.
>
> We are sorry for inconvenience but this is a necessary measure that
>   will help us deliver our services to you faster and more reliably.
>
> For FOSS developers: we welcome free and open source software and are
>   willing to help you. If you want to use OWM data in your free software
>   application please register an API key and file a ticket describing
>   your application and API key registered. OWM will review your request
>   lift access limits for your key if used in open source application.

Comment: Yes but when I use $jsonPHP["weather"][0]["id"]; I get Undefined index: weather

Comment: You forget that I cannot access  http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139 since I don't have *APPID*, so I made a simulation for the respond, saving it as a * json* file, and I get the correct output. I get `804`, which is correct!

Comment: Yeah but this is what you actually get from the var_dump for it http://pastebin.com/KteUqtqc I tried to access the [list][0]['weather'] and it works its just I cant transform it into a string

Comment: So I accidentally come to visit this again, it seems that there was miscommunication/misunderstanding between us. What did I actually mean is that, the json response I posted above is the response for *`lat=35&lon=139`*. As I don't have such *APPID*, so I copy & save the text (response) as a json file (* .json), and try to accessed it. If for that response you get error for the *`["weather"][0]["id"];`*, then it's either we got different json structure (as I saw the country in the *pastebin* is *USA* while mine is *Japan*) or.. they have totally changed the structure of the response :D.